# Make sure to start component names with a capital letter

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-icons

## Problem

I'm having an error using `react-icons` trying to use it:

[image]

in `header.js` I checked for uncapitalized first letter but all of them were correct:

```
  <View style={styles.headerIcon}>
<TouchableOpacity  onPress={openMenu} >
  <MdMap />
</TouchableOpacity>
  </View> 

import
```

## What I have tried

> Deleting `react-icons` then re-installing it `yarn add react-icons` --save.

> Doing what the error says `Make sure to start component names with capital letter`.

And what I have tried didn't work.

I have fixed the error from the help of the answer below that worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this package cannot be used in react-native (component packages typically don't unless they specify compatibility with RN), and you should consider switching to something like [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons).